# How to show specific div when button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making a dress up simulator (that can be rotate 360) but since I'm just a newbie, I can't figure out the logic on how am I suppose to show the necklace or bag when the mannequin faces front. Here's a sample of my code:

**JS**

```
<script>
function toggle_div(id) {

    var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

    if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
        divelement.style.display = 'block';
    else
        divelement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    varSide = 0
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 

    function myFunctionLeft(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
        var a = document.getElementById(id1);
        var b = document.getElementById(id2);
        var c = document.getElementById(id3);
        var d = document.getElementById(id4);

        if (varSide==0){
            varSide = -1;
            a.style.display = 'block';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if (varSide==-1){
            varSide = 2;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if (varSide==2){
            varSide = 1;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'block';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else{
            varSide = 0;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'block';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    } 

    function myFunctionRight(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
        var a = document.getElementById(id1);
        var b = document.getElementById(id2);
        var c = document.getElementById(id3);
        var d = document.getElementById(id4);

        if (varSide==0){
            varSide = 1;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'block';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if (varSide==1){
            varSide = 2;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else if (varSide==2){
            varSide = -1;
            a.style.display = 'block';
            b.style.display = 'none';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else{
            varSide = 0;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            b.style.display = 'block';
            c.style.display = 'none';
            d.style.display = 'none';
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    }
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

case 's2 d1':
echo "s2 d1";
  echo "<div id='id1'><img src='http://i64.tinypic.com/2r77g29.png'></div>";
  echo "<div id='id2'><img src='http://i63.tinypic.com/zufbxj.png'></div>";
  echo "<div id='id3'><img src='http://i67.tinypic.com/9zokg6.png'></div>";
  echo "<div id='id4'><img src='http://i64.tinypic.com/zu13jt.png'></div>";     
break;
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

PS: here's my website, it's undone: http://preziosalacrem.com/DRESSUP/index.php

Comment: What defines the mannequin, with respect to coding, when she faces front?

Comment: I don't *quite* understand what you want. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Hello @8protons and Chris. I didn't posted the whole codes because it's too long but my point is that when <div id='id1'> is present, I'm able to click and show a new div. Like: mannequin (faces front) > clicks necklace button > it will show: mannequin + necklace. But if the mannequin faces right, left or back, the div for the necklace will not show.

Comment: "I can't figure out the logic on how am I suppose to show the necklace or bag when the mannequin faces front" explicitely says that you're having issues displaying the necklace when it's facing front. What you just commented now, "if the mannequin faces right, left or back, the div for the necklace will not show" implies that your original problem of the necklace not loading when facing front does not seem to be your actual problem. Which is it? The necklace/bag not showing when facing front or the necklace/bag not showing when the mannequin is _not_ facing front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**I can't figure out the logic on how am I suppose to show the necklace or bag when the mannequin faces front.**"

So when rotating your mannequin, either left or right, certain values change. In the case that the mannequin is facing the front, the code is as follows:

```
varSide = -1;
a.style.display = 'block';
b.style.display = 'none';
c.style.display = 'none';
d.style.display = 'none';
```

As I swap through views, I can see the code dynamically update in my console's browser so I'm confident that the above state of code is what is set when the mannequin is "facing the front".

[image]

Since you've set a variable that represents the state of position for the mannequin,

```
varSide = -1;
```

then when you load the mannequin's assets, simply do some conditional statement like the following *before* you load the necklace asset:

```
if mannequin has necklace {
    if (varSide === -1) {
    //which means that the mannequin is facing front
        load necklace
    }
}
```